Noob needs help for a calculated column "Total"
I'm creating 10 columns with yes/no answers and want each yes to equal 10%.
Then I want a Total column at the end that adds up each yes (10%) to give me a score out of 100%.
Is anyone able to help me please?
Basic question probably but I can't find the answer.
Thank you.

SharePoint calculated column uses same as Excel like Excel formulas. Try creating your formula in Excel and then copy that to SharePoint. It will reduce your time.

You can create a new calculated column of type Number with this formula:
=IF([Question1],0.1,0) + IF([Question2],0.1,0) + IF([Question3],0.1,0) + IF([Question4],0.1,0) + IF([Question5],0.1,0) + IF([Question6],0.1,0) + IF([Question7],0.1,0) + IF([Question8],0.1,0) + IF([Question9],0.1,0) + IF([Question10],0.1,0)

Replace Question1, Question2, etc. by the internal name of your columns.

Note: depending to your culture, in the formula

the separator , should be ;
the decimal value 0.1 should be 0,1
the IF should be translated (SI in French, etc.)



